# SQL Case NOT IN not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why does SQL Case 'not in' not work? 'in' works though it does not match for 'not in'.

Or perhaps there is a better way to do it?

I am trying to apply a result to a match that meets on criteria set so long as it does not meet the other criteria set.

Thank you

```html
---------- Newsletters ----------

CASE WHEN ( C.ID in  (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND YearLevel = 0 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry')
   AND C.ID not in (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND YearLevel > 0 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry')
   )
   OR
   ( C.ID in  (SELECT  [ContactSpouseID]  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND YearLevel = 0 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry')
   AND C.ID not in (SELECT  [ContactSpouseID]  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND YearLevel > 0 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry')
   )
   OR
   ( ESC.ContactEnquiryID in  (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND YearLevel = 0 AND ReferenceTable = 'Enquiry')
   AND ESC.ContactEnquiryID not in (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND YearLevel > 0 AND ReferenceTable = 'Enquiry')
   )
 THEN 'K' 

 ELSE 

CASE WHEN ( C.ID in  (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND YearLevel > 0 AND YearLevel < 7 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry')
   AND C.ID not in (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND YearLevel = 0 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry')
   AND C.ID not in (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND YearLevel > 6 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry')
   )
   OR
   ( C.ID in  (SELECT  [ContactSpouseID]  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND YearLevel > 0 AND YearLevel < 7 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry')
   AND C.ID not in (SELECT  [ContactSpouseID]  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND YearLevel = 0 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry')
   AND C.ID not in (SELECT  [ContactSpouseID]  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND YearLevel > 6 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry')
   )
   OR
   ( ESC.ContactEnquiryID in  (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND YearLevel > 0 AND YearLevel < 7 AND ReferenceTable = 'Enquiry')
   AND ESC.ContactEnquiryID not in (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND YearLevel = 0 AND ReferenceTable = 'Enquiry')
   AND ESC.ContactEnquiryID not in (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND YearLevel > 6 AND ReferenceTable = 'Enquiry')
   )
   
 THEN '1-6' 

  ELSE 

CASE WHEN ( C.ID in  (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND YearLevel > 6 AND YearLevel < 13 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry')
   AND C.ID not in (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND YearLevel < 7 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry')
   )
   OR
   ( C.ID in  (SELECT  [ContactSpouseID]  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND YearLevel > 6 AND YearLevel < 13 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry')
   AND C.ID not in (SELECT  [ContactSpouseID]  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND YearLevel < 7 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry')
   )
   OR
   ( ESC.ContactEnquiryID in  (SELECT  [ContactSpouseID]  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND YearLevel > 6 AND YearLevel < 13 AND ReferenceTable = 'Enquiry')
   AND ESC.ContactEnquiryID not in (SELECT  [ContactSpouseID]  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND YearLevel < 7 AND ReferenceTable = 'Enquiry')
   )
 THEN '7-6' 

  ELSE 

CASE WHEN ( C.ID in  (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry')
   )
   OR
   ( C.ID in  (SELECT  [ContactSpouseID]  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry')
   )
   OR
   ( ESC.ContactEnquiryID in  (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND ReferenceTable = 'Enquiry')
   )

 THEN 'General'

  ELSE ''  END END

 END 
END AS ProspectiveNews,
```

Comment: Try `AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT  *  FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND YearLevel > 0 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry' AND [ContactID] = C.ID)`

Comment: Thank you though it doesnt seem to like the syntax:

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXISTS'.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it needs to be: `CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND YearLevel > 0 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry' AND [ContactID] = C.ID) Then 'K' Else ... `

Comment: Thanks that worked!

Comment: Do you want to write that in as an answer so i can mark it as the answer?

Comment: Sure, thanks - will do

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that this cannot be rewritten using `LEFT JOIN`s?

Comment: This SQL looks terrible, absolutely a nightmare of maintenance

Comment: Do you have suggestions to make it clean?

Comment: It take about 2min to run. If there is a quicker way I would be happy to know!

Comment: @GaborSch any suggestions to make this code clean and quick?

Comment: @Eric any suggestions to make this code clean and quick?

Comment: @SSS It would be nice if you could clarify that which column belongs to which table. You have a table aliases `C` and `ĘSC`, and you have the `uvLSProspectiveContacts` table. I suppose that all the `ContactID`, `ContactSpouseID`, `EnrolDate`, `YearLevel`, and `ReferenceTable` belong to the `uvLSProspectiveContacts` table. Perhaps a table definition would help a lot.

Comment: Perhaps you could speed up some factors by adding proper index to `uvLSProspectiveContacts`, that contains `EnrolDate`, `YearLevel ` and `ReferenceTable `. The next step would be to rewrite the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `NOT EXISTS`:

```
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [Customers].[dbo].[uvLSProspectiveContacts]
WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND YearLevel > 0 AND
ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry' AND [ContactID] = C.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to NULLs hell.
replace every

```
x not in (select col from t)
```

with

```
x not in (select col from t where col is not null)
```

(unless you know that x is defined as `NOT NULL`)

---

`x not in (a,b,c,...)`
is a shortcut for
`((x <> a) and (x <> b) and (x <> c) and ...)`
If one of the values (e.g. `b`) is NULL then the condition is `NULL <> b`.
since nothing is different from NULL this predicate is not fulfilled and it fails the whole condition.

Comment: @SSS, please take a look

Comment: The predicate is *not* `FALSE` when you compare with `NULL`, it's *unknown*. You can easily demonstrate this by wrapping the entire predicate with `NOT (...)` and you'll see that it's not become `TRUE` (which it would be if it was originally `FALSE`). It's still `UNKNOWN`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever. Thanks. My bad.